# C++ template instantiation pointer null error

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers, instantiation

I want to write my own version of stack, this is what I have:

```
template<class myStackType> class myStackClass
{
    myStackType array[1000];
    int size;
public:
    myStackClass()
    {
        size = 0;
    }
    void pop()
    {
        size--;
    }
    void push(myStackType a)
    {
        array[size] = a;
        size++;
    }
    myStackType top()
    {
        return array[size-1];
    }
    bool empty()
    {
        return(size == 0);
    }
};
```

but when I try to actually use it

```
struct grade
{    
    int mid;
    int final;
    string name;
    grade(int mid1 = 0, int final1 = 0, string name1 = 0)
    {
        mid = mid1;
        final = final1;
        name = name1;
    }
};

myStackClass<grade> myStack;
```

I get a debug assertion failed: invalid null pointer

on the other hand, the std::stack works just fine in the same spot with the same data type

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: if I'm not wrong the stack grows as the user inserts more and more. why did you make it have maximum 1000 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
string name1 = 0
```

It tries to construct a `string` from a `const char*` which is `0` - and this is not allowed. You probably meant:

```
string name1 = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning 0 to a string in your constructor.  That's the bug. The compiler is trying to interpret the 0 as a char *, i. e. a C-style string.  But since it's a 0, it is interpreted as a NULL pointer.

You may also want to do some error checking to make sure your stack doesn't overflow, or that you don't try to pop off an empty stack.

Comment: That was it, thanks - although now I am confused why it worked with std::stack instead of mine.. oh well, thanks

Comment: That depends on how the stack class allocates its storage. If std::stack is using a T* it does not need to actually allocate any T in its constructor. Yours is using an array, so if I remember correctly, every element in the storage is going to be initialized, T() is going to be called, and, yes, then the string = nullptr is going to happen and crash ensues